# Moment.js, get days in other locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using http://momentjs.com and i don't know how to change the locale.

For example :

```
var shortDay = moment(myDate).format('ddd');
```

This line return, depend of the days, Sun Mon ... Fri Sat. I want to return the same, but in french.

I tried `var shortDay = moment(myDate).locale('fr').format('ddd');` but no effect. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the relevant locale file

See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-browser/

Then you just need to call `moment().locale('fr')` once and it will start using french.